# Google Cloud Storage support of S3 multipart upload

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-storage, aws-sdk

Currenty, i'm using GCS in "interoperability mode" to make it accept S3 API requests. By using the official multipart upload example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html) (+ setting the appropriate endpoint), the first initiation POST request:

```
POST /bucket/object?uploads HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.googleapis.com
Authorization: AWS KEY:SIGNATURE
Date: Wed, 07 Jan 2015 13:34:04 GMT
User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.5 Linux/3.13.0-43-generic Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/24.72-b04/1.7.0_72
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

results in this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 55
Date: Wed, 07 Jan 2015 13:34:05 GMT
Server: UploadServer ("Built on Dec 19 2014 ...")
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.02

The request's content type is not accepted on this URL.
```

Could that be an AWS client issue or GCS doesn't support S3's multipart upload yet?

Most of the other actions i have tried (download object, list bucket objects etc) seem to work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** As of May 2021, Google Cloud Storage (GCS) supports S3-compatible multipart uploads. 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/multipart-uploads

The AWS SDK will work seamlessly once you configure the appropriate endpoint.

<s>GSC doesn't support the S3 multipart upload interface.
If you want to perform a chunk-parallel upload you can use object composition - see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects</s>

Comment: Thanks Mike. I guess this "object composition" XML API is available only on GCS (and not on S3), right? If so, i should check if it'd be better to use GCS native [resumable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable) or [multipart](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#multipart) upload APIs directly.

Comment: Yes, the object composition API is GCS-specific. By the way, one other comment: The GCS JSON API does support a multipart upload interface (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#multipart) but it's not the same as the S3 parallel upload API.

Answer (score 7):

Google Cloud Storage (GCS) [now supports the S3-style multipart upload API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-multipart). As such, use cases like the one in this question should just work.