# Unable to use GCS bucket for helm/based kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, kubernetes-helm

Using official / stable `jenkins` helm [release](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins) to install the chart on `kubernetes`.

Using a GCS bucket as destination in the corresponding section of the `values.yaml` file

```
backup:
  enabled: true
  # Used for label app.kubernetes.io/component
  componentName: "jenkins-backup"
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  labels: {}
  annotations: {}
  image:
    repository: "maorfr/kube-tasks"
    tag: "0.2.0"
  extraArgs: []
  # Add existingSecret for AWS credentials
  existingSecret: {}
  env: []
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
  # Destination to store the backup artifacts
  # Supported cloud storage services: AWS S3, Minio S3, Azure Blob Storage, Google Cloud Storage
  # Additional support can added. Visit this repository for details
  # Ref: https://github.com/maorfr/skbn
  destination: "gs://jenkins-backup-240392409"
```

However, when the backup job starts, I get the following in its logs:

```
gs not implemented
```

**edit**: To address the issue raised by @Maxim in a comment below, the pod's description indicates that the quotes do not end up in the backup command

```
Pod Template:
  Labels:           <none>
  Service Account:  my-service-account
  Containers:
   jenkins-backup:
    Image:      maorfr/kube-tasks:0.2.0
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      kube-tasks
    Args:
      simple-backup
      -n
      jenkins
      -l
      app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-jenkins
      --container
      jenkins
      --path
      /var/jenkins_home
      --dst
      gs://my-destination-backup-bucket-6266
```

Comment: It looks like it may not be parsing the destination value correctly. Try removing the double quotes (`"`) around it so it looks like `destination: gs://jenkins-backup-240392409`

Comment: I disagree with Maxim's suggestion, since that is legal YAML; it is **far** more likely to be that [gcs S3 API does not support multipart uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830881)

Comment: So there is a chance `gs` is not actually supported by the backup tool used from the official `jenkins` `helm` charts?

Comment: check also my update on the original question

Answer (score 1):

you should change the "**gs"** in destination to **"gcs"**:

```
destination: "gcs://jenkins-backup-240392409"
```

however you can use ThinBackup plugin in jenkins and the backup is straighforward. [check this guide for full instructions and walkthrough](https://medium.com/faun/backing-up-jenkins-to-google-cloud-storage-4ba12e69ded2).

Comment: Although I had initially accepted your answer, I see that (at least according to the [documentation](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L578)) GCS is supposed to be supported

Comment: you are right sorry for misunderstanding. I unpdated my answer. you should use "gcs" instead of "gs". please accept the answer if that works for you because this will help the community.