# Google cloud storage equivalent for S3 multipart upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, boto3, google-cloud-storage

We are migrating from S3 to GCS and one of the functionalities that needs to be supported in GCS is the ability to upload large files in a multi-part fashion. S3 boto provides us with functions like `initiate_multipart_upload` and `copy_part_from_key` which I currently use for uploading large files in multiple parallel chunks.

I have seen similar discussion on stackoverflow in below two questions

- [Google cloud storage compatibility with aws s3 multipart upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61499378/google-cloud-storage-compatibility-with-aws-s3-multipart-upload)
- [Google Cloud Storage support of S3 multipart upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830432/google-cloud-storage-support-of-s3-multipart-upload)

Both the discussions point to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-multipart) which talks about an XML API to achieve this. However I'm looking for a python based implementation which uses storage.client() methods to stay consistent with rest of our integrations.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the multipart upload in Cloud Storage is only available using the XML API approach.

Alternatively you could use [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads), as this is the recommended way to upload large files using the GCS client.

Finally, you could also open a [Feature Request in Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0) so that this can be considered by their product team.

Answer (score 0):

You can just upload parts simultaneously and merge them at end.

The merging is called "Composition" at Google: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composing-objects#create-composite-rest

Boto3 doesn't allow this operation.